# Null Pointer Exception Fix - Lists

Tags: java, list, nullpointerexception

```
  public void createGraph () {
    int oldFrom = -1;
    int oldTo = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
      EdgeI e = edges.get(i);
      int from = e.from;
      int to = e.to;
      VertexI v = vertices.get(from);
      if (from == oldFrom && to == oldTo){
        vertexWeight wic = v.neighbors.get(v.neighbors.size() - 1);
        wic.w++;
      }
      else {
        v.neighbors.add(new vertexWeight (to, 1));
        oldFrom = from;
        oldTo = to;
      }
    }
  }
```

`neighbors` is a public `List` from `VertexI` class. `w` is a public integer from `vertexWeight` class. `edges` is a list located in my main class. I keep getting a null pointer exception for this line of code:

```
v.neighbors.add(new vertexWeight (to, 1));
```

Tried working on it for around 15 minutes and I didn't get it to work. What am I messing up on?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tester.createGraph(tester.java:60)
    at tester.main(tester.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: Currently you are missing stacktrace of exception ! Show your stacktrace!

Comment: Which is the line it crashes on - the codee doesn't say which is line 60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Initialize `v.neighbors` with `new ArrayList()` in `vertices.get()`.

**Long answer**

Your question omitted a crucial information: How you initialized `neighbors`. Why is this important?

See: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/220060)

In your case I guessed that either `v` or `neighbors` is null during the run of the program. For example `vertices.get(from)` could return null and `v.neighbors` won't work. Or `neighbors` is null, and `v.neighbors.add()` won't work.

And voilà. You admitted that you set `neighbors` to null when initializing `VertexI`.

The solution is: Initialize with `new ArrayList()` instead of `null`.

If that would not have been possible or you cannot avoid null pointers for some other reason, you can do null pointer checks like this:

```
if (v != null && v.neighbors != null) {
    v.neighbors.add(new vertexWeight (to, 1));
}
```

This means, don't add vertices if `v` or `neighbors` are null.

But this is complicated and error-prone. It is easier to avoid null pointers as much as possible. Some would say, avoid them at all costs! Throw an exception instead or return an "empty" object like `new ArrayList()`.

Comment: All EdgeI objects are positive, to and from are always positive.

Comment: I actually created all these V objects in a previous method. When i created these v objects I had to make it (Null, String). Is that the reason? The null takes the spot of the neighbors list.

Comment: And voilà! `neighbors` must be never null or you need to do a null pointer check. I am going to update my answer.

Comment: Ok, how would I go about fixing this? If I am creating an object v in a previous method should I just put an empty list?